# How to replace a searched line with new contents in eclipse?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, log4j

I am working on a big project which has thousand of Java Files. What i have to do is replace all the `System.out.println("Argument")` lines used in the code with log4j logging.I can find the line which uses `System.out.println(...)` by following regex `System\.out.*;`. is there a way to replace the println call with

```
LGR.info( LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? "Argument": null);
```

This is how it should look:

Before:

```
System.out.println("Argument")
```

After:

```
LGR.info( LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? "Argument": null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use File search:

- Check `Case sensitive` and `Regular expression`
- Containing text: `System\.out\.println\((.+)\);`
- File name patterns: `*.java`
- Click `Replace...`
- Check `Regular expression`
- With: `LGR.info( LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? \1 : null);`

Comment: Thanks man you saved my day. It would be great if you explain what you just did.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on a search result in the `Search` view, there is an option called `Replace All ...`. A dialog opens that allows you to enter the replacement text. If a regular expression was used during the search, it also allows to use matcher groups from the regex in the replacement.

There is also an option `Replace selected ...` if you don't want to replace all occurences.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work using search tool `(CTRL+F)` or File Search `(CTRL+H)`

```
search: (System\.out\.println\((.+)\));
replace: LGR.info( LGR.isInfoEnabled() ? $2: null);
```